# Magento 1.9 Show No Payment Methods But i enable Payflow Link

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway, paypal-payflow-pro

I set Enable Payflow Link in Payment Method on my website. but when i go to checkout on Payment Method it show **"No Payment Methods"**
I don't know why this issue is happen?

Comment: I can enable Check / Money Order method but all payment about paypal cannot wordking show no payment methods

Comment: please setup the credentials from paypal. https://prnt.sc/mgbt6m

Comment: @HIrenKadivar Thank you for your comment.it's working but Now it show " You will be redirected to the PayPal website. "   and i don't want redirect i want customers pay without leaving my site.  Help me please Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

please setup the credentials from paypal. more information to refere this link.

https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-paypal-payments-standard-with-magento-community-edition-1.7.x-1.9.x-ts1524

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it's not working.(TOT)  Can i add your skpe or facebook for talk my proble about magento? I've tried setting up for many days. but cannot working. Thank you

Comment: yes i wil setup in my free time. please add your account skype.